# Shell script copying lines from multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have multiple files which have the same structure but not the same data. Say their names are values_#####.txt (values_00001.txt, values_00002.txt, etc.).

I want to extract a specific line from each file and copy it in another file. For example, I want to extract the 8th line from values_00001.txt, the 16th line from values_00002.txt, the 24th line from values_00003.txt and so on (increment = 8 each time), and copy them line by line in a new file (say values.dat).

I am new to shell scripting, I tried to use sed, but I didn't figure out how to do that.

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Are the lines always equally spaced (start with X, increment by X)?

Comment: Yes, here is an example of a file (a bit of it) :
 `0.00000E+00  4.94791E+02
  1.00000E-05  4.94539E+02
  3.00000E-05  4.94041E+02
  5.00000E-05  4.93551E+02
  7.00000E-05  4.93067E+02
  9.00000E-05  4.92591E+02
  1.10000E-04  4.92121E+02
  1.30000E-04  4.91657E+02
  1.50000E-04  4.91200E+02
  1.70000E-04  4.90749E+02
  1.90000E-04  4.90304E+02
  2.10000E-04  4.89864E+02
  2.30000E-04  4.89430E+02
  2.50000E-04  4.89002E+02
  2.70000E-04  4.88579E+02
  2.90000E-04  4.88162E+02
  3.10000E-04  4.87749E+02
  3.30000E-04  4.87342E+02
  3.50000E-04  4.86940E+02
  3.70000E-04  4.86542E+02`

Comment: @user3116130 it's better to update your question with the sample input. In comments, code is not properly showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ordering of files is also important to make sure you get output in desired sequence.

Consider this script:

```
n=8
while read f; do
   sed $n'q;d' "$f" >> output.txt
   ((n+=8))
done < <(printf "%s\n" values_*.txt|sort -t_ -nk2,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can make it:

```
for var in {1..NUMBER}
do
    awk -v line=$var 'NR==8*line' values_${var}.txt >> values.dat
done
```

#### Explanation

- The `for` loop is basic.
- `-v line=$var` "gives" the `$var` value to `awk`, so it can be used with the variable `line`.
- `'NR==8*line'` prints the line number `8*{value we are checking}`.
- `values_${var}.txt` gets the file `values_1.txt`, `values_2.txt`, and so on.
- `>> values.dat` redirects to `values.dat` file.

#### Test

I created 3 equal files `a1`, `a2`, `a3`. They contain 30 lines, being each one the line number:

```
$ cat a1
1
2
3
4
...
```

Executing the one liner:

```
$ for var in {1..3}; do awk -v line=$var 'NR==8*line' a${var} >> values.dat; done
$ cat values.dat 
8
16
24
```